# PHP: What is that character encoding of this string?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

In PHP, i have the following string: `=CA=CC=D1=C8=C9`

what is its character encoding?

Comment: In what encoding? Can you give some context?

Comment: It's a very happy smile surrounded by four very sad smiles, all delimited by random letters. `=C =C =D =C =C` This format tried to make it into JSON for standardized emotions transmission, but it was rejected because of the random letters; the next revision will probably use whitespace.

Comment: @Matteo: Actually "AC189" is a magic number used in encoding the DRM for Sony's new cassette tape format, and they banned it for legal reasons. This isn't widely known, though, as they wanted to keep it quiet. Please don't tell anyone I mentioned it! (It's ironic that the string of smilies represents Sony surrounded by their customers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called quoted printable

I can deceode it using :

```
quoted_printable_decode($string);
```

Answer (score 6):

[**It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses.**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Those 5 bytes mean different things in different encodings.

- In UTF-8, it's invalid.  All lead bytes and no trail bytes.
- In ISO-8859-1 and windows-1252, it's the string `ÊÌÑÈÉ`.
- According to [chardet](http://chardet.feedparser.org/), it's in KOI8-R, and decodes to `йляхи`

Comment: Are they any way to convert it to UTF-8. It contans Arabic language.

Comment: In that case, it's probably ISO-8859-6 or windows-1256, and decodes to `تجربة`.  The UTF-8 equivalent is `=D8=AA=D8=AC=D8=B1=D8=A8=D8=A9`.

Comment: can you give me a php code for decode the text (If It is windows-1256)

Comment: Five bytes is in general far too short for guessing by something like `chardet`. In any case, `chardet` doesn't grok any charset that is used for Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer and comments that you got assumed that you knew already that the transportation encoding was "quoted-printable" ... decoding  using that, "=CA=CC=D1=C8=C9" becomes "\xCA\xCC\xD1\xC8\xC9" (which is NOT UTF-8, as you asked for in a comment) ... and they concentrated on what encoding might reasonably be used to produce Unicode out of that. To arrive at UTF-8, you need two more steps: decode "\xCA\xCC\xD1\xC8\xC9" into Unicode (using an encoding appropriate to Arabic text) and then encode into UTF-8.